# discrete math, problem on combinations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

there are 6 undercase letters in a password, how many passwords are there if you have to use at least one 'a'??  I have calculated the total number of passwords which is 26^6 and I have calculated the amount with just one 'a' which is 6*25^5, i just need don't know how to do it when it comes with the at least one.

Comment: try to count the number of passwords without any $a$'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What is the opposite of "at least one `a`"? Since you know how many total passwords there are, you can find the number of unacceptable passwords, and the subtract from the total.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the complement in which the string has no a. How many such possible strings are there?

There are 25^6 possible strings with no a.

There are 26^6 possible strings with no restrictions.

So 26^6 - 25^6 are the number of strings with at least one a. We removed all strings that have no a and are left with the desired result.